# PowerShell datatype conversion from user specified string value to array is not resulting correct result

Tags: powershell

When I convert the variable value which is in string to an array format, it converted data type to an array but the result is not an array.

Example:

```
cls
#Actual String value concatenated with dot (.)
$EmpInfo="Name.Address.Pincode.Phone"
Write-Host $EmpInfo

#Change string value to array format
$EmpInfoArray= '"'+$EmpInfo.Replace('.',""",""")+'"'
Write-Host $EmpInfoArray
$EmpInfoArray.gettype()

#Convert BaseType value from 'system.object' to 'system.array'
[Array]$ConvertedArray = $EmpInfoArray
$ConvertedArray.GetType()

Write-Host $ConvertedArray.Count
Write-Host $ConvertedArray[0]
```

Result:

1

"Name","Address","Pincode","Phone"

It is not resulting the value as an array. If it is an array then the result would be array count 4 and first array value 'Name'

Do we have any workaround to result the converted user specified string value to an array.

Answer (score 1):

Split your EmpInfoArray with ','

`[Array]$ConvertedArray = $EmpInfoArray -split ','`

Comment: -split ',' resulting value with Quotation mark. But it should result only the array value (Name) not enclosing with quotation mark ("Name"). For this again I need to replace the Quotation with space.

Comment: `$EmpInfoArray= $EmpInfo.Replace('.',',')`
This works as well, along with my above recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke-expression fixed this issue. Now it is resulting as an array.

```
cls
#Actual String value concatenated with dot (.)
$EmpInfo="Name.Address.Pincode.Phone"
Write-Host $EmpInfo

#Change string value to array format
$EmpInfoArray = invoke-expression ('"'+$EmpInfo.Replace('.',""",""")+'"')
$EmpInfoArray.gettype()
$EmpInfoArray.count
$EmpInfoArray[0]
```

Result:

```
4
Name
```